# Проксирование сайта

Tags: php, nginx, apache, proxy

Мне необходимо проксировать некоторое кол-во сайтов создать зеркало. При запросе на мой домен, мой сервер должен отправлять request на сервер где расположен сайт, после чего получать дату, немного видоизменять некоторые элементы DOM дерева и отправлять посетителю. Самое сложное, необходимо сохранить авторизацию в случае если пользователь авторизовался. Я примерно понимаю как это реализовать со старыми сайтами, там все довольно просто, но если у сайта будет много запросов с JS токенами и т д? Возможно будет React или Angular на frontend e или другой JS фреймворк.
Есть несколько готовых решений по обходу CORS но в голове нет картины как такое реализовать.

Как это можно реализовать? Нужен совет опытного разработчика. Может уже есть готовые решения? Желательно в рамках LAMP

Comment: А как Вы собираетесь через свой сайт проксировать https?

Comment: С большинством сайтов такое не прокатит, так что возможность или невозможность такого проксирования нужно рассматривать для конкретного сайта, а в абстрактном случае ответ — никак

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему не прокатит? Может быть JS-куки и не поставятся, но для большинства сайтов это и не нужно. Да и HTTPS легко проксировать, только в куках заменять домен. Как раз для большинства сайтов прокатывает. Я Google проксировал на своём домене. Поиск работал нормально.

Comment: @DiD, А какие технологии использовались для проксирования?

Comment: Ну я просто сделал прокладку из одного php-файла, на который посылались все запросы. В куках правил домен. JS куки в какой-то степени тоже работали, так как скрипты пробрасывались браузеру, но в скриптах ничего не исправлял, и там возможно что-то и косячит. Но в те времена, например, тот же Google мог работать и с полностью выключенным JS в браузере.